# How would I write the package.json version to my WebPack bundle?

Tags: node.js, webpack

My package.json file includes a version for my module, which ultimately get's compiled into an app.bundle.js file that I include in my web project. I would REALLY like to have the version number from the package.json file written to the app.bundle.js file as a comment right at the beginning of the file.

Is there a WebPack plugin to do this or a setting with WebPack itself?

Comment: If you need to have version number available in your code, use the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) instead. Also, see [this example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/237#issuecomment-69438616 ) if you want to get the version number directly from you package.json file.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Webpack comes with a [BannerPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#bannerplugin) that adds a banner to the top of each generated chunk.

You can require your `package.json` and use it as any regular JavaScript object to get the `version` field.

```
var PACKAGE = require('./package.json');
var version = PACKAGE.version;
```

Then use it to generate the desired banner string that will be used in the `BannerPlugin`.

### webpack.config.js

```
var PACKAGE = require('./package.json');
var banner = PACKAGE.name + ' - ' + PACKAGE.version;

module.exports = {
  // Other stuff
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(banner)
  ]
};
```

I have used it to add the version from the `package.json` file and other info to the top of a library of my own. Check the [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/dreyescat/react-rating/blob/v0.1.0/webpack.config.js#L2-L6) of this project for a working example.

Comment: Note: If you are using `UglifyJsPlugin`, make sure to add the `BannerPlugin` after the `UglifyJsPlugin`.

Answer (score 3):

## 2022 update

In Webpack 5, `TerserPlugin` is included ["out of the box"](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#getting-started) (i.e. no need to install another plugin).

I've had a good experience using something like the following:

```js
optimization: {
  minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
    terserOptions: {
      format: {
        preamble: `/* Copyright ${new Date().getUTCFullYear()}, XYZ Corp. ${require('./package.json').name} ${require('./package.json').version} (${new Date().toUTCString()}) */`
      }
    }
  })],
}
```

The above will result in the following being prefixed onto your bundle:

```
/* Copyright 2022, XYZ Corp. package-name 1.0.0 (Thu, 05 May 2022 20:03:36 GMT) */
```