# Webpack: generate comments in output files with project version

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a Webpack project who's output JavaScript and CSS files will be used in other projects.

How can I generate a version comment at the top of these files based on the version I specify in `package.json`?

```
// bundle.js
// v1.0.0

/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
```

I would also like this in the CSS file.

```
// styles.css
// v1.0.0

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
```

Comment: Have you looked into the webpack plugins https://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-plugin.html ?

Comment: Do you have one in mind or are you suggesting I build one?

Comment: This looks promising https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#bannerplugin

Comment: Yeah, I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799996/3446655

Comment: Good to know that there is something already out there.

Comment: Her'e's the updated doc page https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx